# How to remove transparent whitespace from image after a crop HTML5 Canvas/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I have a function that dynamically produces a cropped section of a world map. The map has various points plotted onto it, plotted by longitude and latitude, depending on the data passed into the function from elsewhere in the script. (Don't worry about how these values are calculated, just accept they are calculated where I have put [number] in my code). I've worked out how to crop my map dynamically, but what I'm noticing is that there is a lot of transparent whitespace to the right of the image after the crop, when the image is appended to a div on the page. How do I remove this whitespace?

Please note that each crop will be of a different size. Setting overflow:hidden property on the containing div and limiting the containing div to a precise pixel width will not achieve what I want to achieve.

Thx u
-- Gaweyne

```
createZoomedMapImage: function(imageURL){
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = _.bind(function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        $canvas = $(canvas),
        w = imageObj.width,
        h = imageObj.height;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  var startingX = [number]
  var starting Y = [number]
  var deltaWidth = [number]
  deltaHeight = [number]
  context.drawImage(imageObj, startingX, startingY, deltaWidth, deltaHeight, 0, 0, (deltaWidth*2), (deltaHeight*2));
  var zoomedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

  }, this);
  imageObj.src = imageURL;
}
```

jsfiddle.net/Gaweyne/r0t3hoo6

The image tag looks like what is displayed in the result. I have an image of, say, 300 x 600px. But the actual graphic only takes up 300 x 300 pixels. I don't want the graphic to take up the full width of the image. I want the image to be 300 x 300 pixels. I don't want to set this explicitly with CSS because the cropped maps will differ in size depending on the data.

Comment: Attach an image of what is the matter.

Comment: I can't. I develop on an offline machine for security. To clarify:

1) I crop the image with the drawImage function
2) I create an img tag with a src attribute of the URL produced in the code above
3) I append it to a div
4) The image appears, but transparent whitespace appears to the right of the image within the image tag.

Comment: Even if you develop offline in a local machine, you should be able to upload an image or even a representation of what is the problem. We won't spend more time helping you that you trying to explain the problem.

Comment: It would take too long to explain why that is not possible. :s

Is there any one part you need me to clarify or do you just not understand all of it?

Comment: Actually I might be able to recreate something in fiddle. Wait right there.

Comment: With the code and the text you wrote, the only solution I come to mind is **width: 100%**. But I'm hopping you already tried that. So just upload something to clarify your needs.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Gaweyne/r0t3hoo6/

Focus on the result, not the HTML markup. The image tag looks like what is displayed in the result.

I have an image of, say, 300 x 600px. But the actual graphic only takes up 300 x 300 pixels. I don't want the graphic to take up the full width of the image. I want the image to be 300 x 300 pixels.

I don't want to set this explicitly with CSS because the cropped maps will differ in size depending on the data.

Comment: So is there any way I can modify the drawImage function, so when it draws the map on the canvas, it crops the map, but doesn't include the whitespace to the right of it?

Comment: Edit the question with the jsfiddle to upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92056/discussion-between-lilezek-and-gaweyne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
canvas.width = deltaWidth;
canvas.height = deltaHeight;
context.drawImage(imageObj, startingX, startingY, deltaWidth, deltaHeight, 0, 0, (deltaWidth*2), (deltaHeight*2));
var zoomedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Comment: Found the bug that was stopping this working while we were in chat. This worked perfectly. Many thanks.

*tips fedora*